# Работа с Cookies на Java с Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

Здравствуйте. 
Столкнулся со следующей задачей - сделать авторизацию(и дальнейшую работу) на определенном сайте через Java приложение. Все упирается в Cookies, не могу понять с ними работать.

Пока что сильно упростил задачу:
Необходимо отправлять первый HTTP запрос с Cookie на свой сайт, после чего отправлять второй HTTP запрос, и получать ответ на него с отправленной ранее Cookie. Вроде бы все элементарно.

Вчера попробовал реализовать это на java.net.HttpURLConnection. 
Но ничего не работало как надо - HTTP запрос с Cookie приходит на мой сайт, cookie пишется (там контрольная php страничка которая записывает в txt все пришедшие запросы и cookie), но в ответе на второй HTTP запрос отправленной Cookie нет.

Погуглил, нашел инфу что все должно работать если использовать Apache HttpClient. Сделал на нем(код ниже), и все равно тоже самое!!!

Я в полном недоумении. Такое впечатление что меняется сессия(не уверен что правильно назвал, не силен в этом).

Как решить эту задачу? Буду очень признателен за любую помощь и подсказку.

Вот так записываю Cookie

```
    public static void set_cookie() throws IOException {


        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        // Populate cookies if needed
        BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("name", "value");


        cookie.setDomain(".control456.ru");
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);

        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
            .build();   

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://control456.ru/sample/save_post_get.php");


        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); //получаем ответ
        System.out.println("записываем куки");        

        //Вывод ответа (код)
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());      

   }
```

А вот так получаю:

```
      public static void get_cookie() throws IOException {

        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();   //назначаем httpclient


        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://control456.ru/sample/save_post_get.php");//Типа GET по указаному адресу



        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); //получаем ответ



        //Вывод ответа (код)

        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());

        //вывод куков
        System.out.println("принимаем куки");
        HeaderIterator it = response.headerIterator("Set-Cookie");
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("куки сайта" + it.next());
       }
```

Comment: Добрый день!
Надеюсь это поможет Вам: [Работа с сессиями cookies](http://spec-zone.ru/RU/Java/Tutorials/networking/cookies/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Записать куку:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("key", "value");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Получить так:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
```

в цикле
    cookies.getValue();

Comment: Это  javax.servlet.http - java EE. Я же пишу обычное клиентское приложение.

Comment: Посмотри это пример может подойдет [ссылка]https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/urlconnection/get-cookies-from-http-connection/

Comment: Это вообще примитивщина. Получить значения куков для меня нет проблем, хоть через  java.net.URLConnection; хоть через Apache Httpclient. Попробую по другому объяснить - в браузере я когад захожу на какую то страницу, которая записывает мне куки, и потом её обновляю, значение кук не меняется. А когда делаю запрос из Java приложения, то на 1 запрос одна кука, а на второй - у же другая, как будто из другого браузера зашел. Т.е. как будто "сессия" срывается.